# How do I create a random path?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm that can generate something like what's in this image:

[image]

I've read about drunken walk algorithms but they don't seem to quite fit what I need. I'm not sure if I can achieve what I'm looking for with a heavily modified drunken walk algorithm or if I should be looking for some other algorithm to mess with.

Comment: The path in that image doesn't seem to cross itself. Is that important for your application?

Comment: @TedHopp Yes, it is important that the path does not cross itself.

Comment: What you want is called a Self Avoiding Randow Walk, usually abbreviated as SAW. Google for it and you will find several generation methods, as it is a well studied and very important issue in physics, chemistry and biology. The ADN, the polymers and other phenomena are related to this kind of things. Don't expect to find easy and efficient algorithms ...

Comment: FWIW, that image looks like a deformed space filling curve. Could it simply be a mapping of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve, like the warped maps at http://www.worldpopulationatlas.org/?

Comment: Why not employing 5 year old kids - It may be cheaper, and has a true random source.

Comment: @Jitamaro, are you here? Finally question for you!! :-)

Comment: @LiorKogan, surely employing 5 year kids would be cheaper, but are you sure they would know programming?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to avoid self-intersection, a random walk is going to be difficult to do correctly.  You could easily paint yourself into a corner.  I would suggest starting with a single line segment that crosses the area, then splitting this line segment somewhere in the middle and shifting the midpoint by some random amount proportional to the length of the line segment.  Repeat this process recursively for the two new line segments.  If you end up with a midpoint that causes one of the two new line segments to cross an existing line segment, then try a different midpoint.  Stop the recursion when your line segments are short (however you want to define that).